# Apache2 ProxyPass / ProxyPassReverse results in 404 for only one out of many directives

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

Apache2, mod_proxy installed, using reverse proxy for more than a dozen sites, works flawlessly for those.  Added one more directive but going to that URL results in a 404 error.

For the purpose of this question the apache server is designated as `web1`.

```
<Ifmodule proxy_module>
 ProxyRequests Off
 <Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

The directive below is an example of what works for all (but one) existing cases.  It's noteworthy that all existing cases pass the request from `/somedirectory` (on `web1`) to `http://somewebserver/somedirectory`.

```
ProxyPass /sample1 http://web2/sample1
ProxyPassReverse /sample1 http://web2/sample1
```

The directive below results in a 404:

```
ProxyPass /sample3 http://web3
ProxyPassReverse /sample3 http://web3
```

The difference is that for `/sample3` the directive points to the root of `web3` rather than a directory on `web3`.

There's also the question whether the 404 is actually being generated by Apache on `web1` or not.  When setting `LogLevel debug` on `web1` the `error_log` does not contain any errors about the `ProxyPass` `ProxyPassReverse` directives.  Likewise the `access_log` on `web1` does not contain any trace of the request to `/sample3`.

This is what the 404 looks like in Firefox/Chrome:

[image: 404]

The goal is to have content located on in the root of `web3` show up as `web1/sample3`.  Due to a number of reasons relocating the content from the root of `web3` to `web3/sample3` is not an option at this time.

Is there a glaring error in my implementation?  If not, what steps can I take to continue troubleshooting this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I like to simplify things when debugging these sorts of issues. From the proxy, what is the response if you use curl to fetch http://web3.  In terms of the URL rewrites/relocation, I would handle that on the backened server and not in the proxy.

Comment: @jeffatrackaid running curl on web1 to fetch web3 works without any issues and returns the entire page.  I am not sure what you mean by handling the rewrites on the backend server.